# Remove quotes around specific string with ReGex Python module?

Tags: python, regex

How can i remove quotation marks around the phrase "Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - "Firstseen: 591230-EF" of only "Firstseen: 591230-EF", so it will become "Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - Firstseen: 591230-EF, using Regex?

Comment: The question isn't clear, why can't you just remove all double quotes?

Comment: Because i need to remove quotes between only a specific pattern. Other quotes must remain... Ex. "This is a long phrase" - "Part 2 of the Phrase" - "Part 3". Lets say i only want to remove quotes around "Part 3" string.

Comment: Regular expressions are very poor at doing these types of context-dependent replacements.

Comment: What is the logic that distinguishes `Part 3` from the other phrases that shouldn't have quotes removed.

Comment: When doing some Analytics, multiple informations on same phrase, separated by commas and other characters, means different things so i cant change them all. Just the ones i want. I will also use this same formula for multiple patterns that uses not only quotes but other special characters as well...

Comment: So it isnt possible using RegEx then?

Comment: Since you haven't clearly explained the logic, it's hard to tell. Is `Part 3` a fixed phrase, or just an example of a pattern that needs to be recorgnized?

Comment: Its a example of a pattern that needs to be regorgnized.

Comment: OK, so what is the general pattern that it's an instance of?

Comment: "Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - "Firstseen: 591230-EF". This is the exact pattern i receive, and i need to remove the quotes around "Firstseen".

Comment: I don't need more examples, I need a general description of the pattern that should be matched, which can then be translated into a regular expression.

Comment: "Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - "Firstseen: 591230-EF" becomes "Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - Firstseen: 591230-EF. This is it.

Comment: Thats not a example. Thats exactly the name of a item i need to filter ._.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace the string surrounded by quotes with just the string. You can use a capture group in the regexp to get the string between the quotes.

```
text = '"Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - "Firstseen: 591230-EF"'
phrase = 'Firstseen: 591230-EF'
new_text = re.sub(f'"({phrase})"', r'\1', text)
print(new_text)
```

Output:

```
"Service Name" - "Users Connected: 359" - Firstseen: 591230-EF
```

If you want to match something other than a fixed string, put that into `phrase`. For instance, you can match two different fixed strings with alternation:

```
phrase = 'Part 3|Data 4'
```

If you want to match any code after `Firstseen`, it would be

```
phrase = r'Firstseen: \d+-[A-Z]+'
```

Comment: Yeah but im not using Python... As i said, its a RegEx pattern for Grafana.

Comment: I don't know Grafana, but I've updated the answer to use a regexp replacement.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comments. Please update the question to explain what you want.

Comment: I changed the question to match your answer. Thanks for your effort. I will make another question with the problem specified more clearly. I went into some problems using your method. For instance, if Firstseen: 591230-EF change to Firstseen: 4925-EF your ReGex stops working.

Comment: Hello. I followed your suggestion and created a new answer containing exactly what i need. I tried stickying to the most detail as possible. Thanks for your suggestion, i went through this one again and indeed it needed more details... If you want, you can give it a try... It's a little bit different than the original. Thanks again for your suggestions and tips for making a clear and detailed question.

Comment: Where is your answer? Do you mean you edited the question? Or you're talking about this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73731406/remove-match-quotes-between-string-using-regex

Comment: Yes i edited to match your answer, since it lacked details. The new one is more detailed and better explained. Also, yes, it is that other question indeed.

Comment: Your comment said you posted a new answer, you meant you posted a new question.

Comment: Yes, new answer solved the problem.